# Javascript Image Replace Coin Flipping

Tags: javascript

I have tried many different ways but this one is my more recent attempt. By running this I cannot get the image to replace the one. My result is correct (heads or tails) wise. But it is not replacing the image.

I have tried other ways but then my results won't show accurately, or won't show at all. I just need help. I am pretty new at this and getting frustrated.

In the code provided, I'm sure something is not serving a purpose or something is not supposed to be where it is. I have tried so many different things that I lost control a few attempts ago.

My Javascript:

```
    var tails = 0;
    var heads = 0;
    var clicks = 0;
    function clicked()
    {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("seq").innerHTML = clicks;
    }

    function toss() {
        var rows = 0;
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
        while (rows < 1) {   
           var arr = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
            {       
                var val = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 );
                if (val === 1) {
                    arr[i] = imageHeads("images/heads.jpg");
                    heads = heads + 1;
                    checkHeads();
                } else {
                    arr[i] = imageTails("images/tails.jpg");
                    tails = tails + 1;
                    checkTails();
                }       
            }
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "<br />" + arr;
            delete arr;
            rows++;
        }
        clicked();
    }

    function checkHeads()
    {
        document.getElementById("headsDisplay").innerHTML = heads;
    }

    function checkTails()
    {
        document.getElementById("tailsDisplay").innerHTML = tails;
    }


    function imageHeads(src) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;

        // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
        document.body.appendChild(img);

    }

    function imageTails(src) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;

        // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
        document.body.appendChild(img);

    }
```

My HTML code snippet:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" id="toss" value=" Flip Coin " onclick="toss()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number of Flips Performed: <span id="seq">0</span></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Heads Count: <span id="headsDisplay">0</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Tails Count: <span id="tailsDisplay">0</span></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td><span id="results"><img id="myImg" src="images/heads.jpg"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I tried to make a fiddle but I can't get it to run properly https://jsfiddle.net/qvqzje82/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qvqzje82/3/ ?

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/qvqzje82/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/qvqzje82/2/) This is working for me. Why? Because I changed the way the JavaScript is loading from the left-top panel on jsfiddle. Changed it from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are creating a new img and appending it to the bosy rather than adding it to the "results" span. Modify your below functions as

```
function imageHeads(src) {
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = src;

// This next line will just add it to the <results> tag
document.getElementById('results').appendChild(img);

}

function imageTails(src) {
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = src;


// This next line will just add it to the <results> tag
document.getElementById('results').appendChild(img);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tails = 0;
var heads = 0;
var clicks = 0;
function clicked()
{
 clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("seq").innerHTML = clicks;
}

function toss() {
    var rows = 0;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
    while (rows < 1) {   
       var arr = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
  {       
            var val = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 );
            if (val === 1) {
                arr[i] = imageHeads("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/2009NativeAmericanRev.jpg/150px-2009NativeAmericanRev.jpg");
    heads = heads + 1;
    checkHeads();
            } else {
                arr[i] = imageTails("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/2010NativeAmerican_Rev.jpg/150px-2010NativeAmerican_Rev.jpg");
    tails = tails + 1;
    checkTails();
            }       
        }
        document.getElementById("results").appendChild(arr[0]);
        delete arr;
        rows++;
    }
 clicked();
}

function checkHeads()
{
 document.getElementById("headsDisplay").innerHTML = heads;
}

function checkTails()
{
 document.getElementById("tailsDisplay").innerHTML = tails;
}


function imageHeads(src) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    return img; 

}

function imageTails(src) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    return img; 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="display">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="button" id="toss" value=" Flip Coin " onclick="toss()"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Number of Flips Performed: <span id="seq">0</span></td>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
  <td>Heads Count: <span id="headsDisplay">0</span></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td>Tails Count: <span id="tailsDisplay">0</span></td>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
  <td><span id="results"><img id="myImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/2009NativeAmericanRev.jpg/150px-2009NativeAmericanRev.jpg"></span></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also stop clearing `<span id="results">` on each toss, and instead replace the `src` of the image that's already there:

```
function imageHeads(src) {
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    img.src = src;
}

function imageTails(src) {
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    img.src = src;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qvqzje82/6/